# Can't bind drawable in switch case using ButterKnife

Tags: java, android, butterknife

So I,ve got an issue with binding views in switch case. I'd create an method, which will set properly ImageView, according to actual weather.

Before I use ButterKnife, this method look like that:

```
public void setWeatherIcon() {
    switch (forecastInfo) {
        case "clear sky":
            weatherIcon.setImageResource(R.drawable.day_clear_sky);
            break;
        case "few clouds":
            weatherIcon.setImageResource(R.drawable.day_few_clouds);
            break;
        case "scattered clouds":
            weatherIcon.setImageResource(R.drawable.scattered_clouds);
            break;
        case "broken clouds":
            weatherIcon.setImageResource(R.drawable.broken_clouds);
            break;
        case "light rain":
            weatherIcon.setImageResource(R.drawable.shower_rain);
            break;
        case "rain":
            weatherIcon.setImageResource(R.drawable.day_rain);
            break;
        case "thunderstorm":
            weatherIcon.setImageResource(R.drawable.thunderstorm);
            break;
        case "snow":
            weatherIcon.setImageResource(R.drawable.snow);
            break;
        case "mist":
            weatherIcon.setImageResource(R.drawable.mist);
            break;
    }
}
```

Now, after using the ButterKnife, I can't use switch case anymore (I'd just show you just first case)

```
public void setWeatherIcon() {
    switch (forecastInfo) {
        case "clear sky":
            @BindDrawable(R.drawable.day_clear_sky); *
            break;
```

- "Annotatins is not allowed here"

Comment: your adding the @BindDrawable to the 'break' ,so its definitely not going to work

Comment: i think you can bind drawable something like this and use the variable in switch caee
@BindDrawable(R.drawable.ic_expand_small_holo_light)
protected Drawable mExpandDrawable;